# Grunt usemin with templates

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

Given the following directory structure:

```
– Gruntfile.js
– app
    |– index.php
    |– js
    |– css
    |– templates
         |– template.php
– dist
```

How can I configure grunt usemin to update the references to styles and scripts in my template file relative to the index.php which uses the template?

currently the tasks look like this:

```
useminPrepare: {
    html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/templates/template.php',
    options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }
},
usemin: {
    html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.php'],
    css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/css/*.css'],
    options: {
        dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
    }
}
```

And the blocks inside of the template look like this:

```
<!-- build:js js/main.js -->
    <script src="js/script1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script2.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I found it out:
The solution is to use the alternate search path option:

```
<!-- build:<type>(alternate search path) <path> -->
... HTML Markup, list of script / link tags.
<!-- endbuild -->
```

The build blocks now look like this:

```
<!-- build:js(app) js/main.js -->
    <script src="js/script1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script2.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

and the usemin task is configured as follows:

```
usemin: {
    html: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/templates/template.php',
    css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/css/*.css'],
    options: {
        dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, it doesn’t work with actual php code inside of template.php.